# Merging vector layers and deleting duplicate geometries

Tags: qgis, geometry, qgis-processing, merge, qgis-2

I merge 3 extracted layers with different counts of parcels but some attributes contain same data.

For example:

[image]

Having same data input creates duplicate parcel, was able to clean this with delete duplicate geometries but encountered another error.

3 merged layers is merged to the original layer and cleaned it once again but it seems that delete duplicate geometries is deleting the data from the extracted layers.

Here are the counts per layer for reference:

Original layer data count: 1,901/18,669 (total parcel counts)
3 extracted layer data count: 7,589
Extracted layer and original layer data count: 7,024/23,792
Cleaned original and extracted layer count: 1,902/18,668

Will there be other options to merge layers without having duplicates?

Comment: You could put all geometries into a new layer w/o the attributes, then delete duplicate geometries, then convert all other parcel-layers to centroids, join the centroids attributes to the cleaned up geometries and finally adjust the attribute table using `coalesce`. Have fun =P

Comment: Thank you, will try this one. :)